# Can't show vectors on zeroes of axes in Python Quiver

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a vector field using numpy and quiver.
Unfortunately, the functions I use for the components of each vector require dividing by the values in the mesh field, so quiver won't show the vectors in which the x, y, or z meshes are 0.
Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
ax = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
vecX3d=np.linspace(-5,5,11)
vecY3d=np.linspace(-5,5,11)
vecZ3d=np.linspace(-5,5,11)
meshVecX3d,meshVecY3d,meshVecZ3d=np.meshgrid(vecX3d,vecY3d,vecZ3d)
print("X",meshVecX3d)
print("Y",meshVecY3d)
print("Z",meshVecZ3d)
componentX = 1/(np.sign(meshVecX3d)*(meshVecX3d**2)) 
componentY = 1/(np.sign(meshVecY3d)*(meshVecY3d**2))
componentZ = 1/(np.sign(meshVecZ3d)*(meshVecZ3d**2))
ax.quiver(meshVecX3d,meshVecY3d,meshVecZ3d,componentX,componentY,componentZ, length=1)
plt.show()
```

My code creates [this field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWtAt.png), with no vectors at the zeroes of the x, y, or z axes.
I also get a few warnings, telling me an invalid value was encountered in multiply, subtract, and true_divide.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you divide a non-zero number by zero, you can say that the result is not a number or consider the limit n/ε for ε→0, that is ∞.  Now you are experiencing the first issue, with Matplotlib not drawing vectors whose components are not a number.  If you use the other approach, writing, e.g., `ε=1E-6 ; vecX3d = np.linspace(-5, 5+ε, 11)` what you get is a quiver plot where the only vectors that are visible are the one originating on the axes, because all the other vectors will have negligible length compared tho the former. TL;DR You can't do that.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to mention: what happens if you write `ε=1E-6 ; vecX3d = np.linspace(-5, 5-ε, 11)` ?  — Answer, the large component changes sign. ፨ ፨ ፨፨ ፨ ፨ Which is the correct result? — Answer, both and none.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Maybe I can fix the sign change with np.sign().